# Hindu Calendar vs Gregorian Calendar

Tags: calendar

How much is the difference between a Hindu Calendar(Shaka Sanwat or Vikrami Sanwat) and Gregorian Calendar. Which Hindu Calendar do we follow in India for dating the festivals?

Comment: of Course we follow Tithi occurance for majority of festivals.